# How do I map the first digit (0) as an Int in an array?

Tags: java

I'm trying to break an int value and save it an array, I tried using this method, it works fine except when the first digit is zero, it saves it as 1 instead of 0. How do I fix this?

```
int k2CombinedEnc = in.nextInt();
int[] k2Enc = Integer.toString(k2CombinedEnc).chars().map(c -> c-='0').toArray(); 
for(int element: k2Enc) {
    System.out.println("encrypted ciphertext is" + element);
}
```

Example output:

```
0010101010
encrypted ciphertext is1
encrypted ciphertext is0
encrypted ciphertext is1
encrypted ciphertext is0
encrypted ciphertext is1
encrypted ciphertext is0
encrypted ciphertext is1
encrypted ciphertext is0
```

Answer (score 3):

You are reading the value as an integer. All leading zeroes are stripped because the number `010` is just `10`.

Read it as a string instead and you should be fine.

```
String k2CombinedEnc = in.nextLine();
int[] k2Enc = k2CombinedEnc.chars().map(c -> c-='0').toArray(); 

for(int element: k2Enc) {
    System.out.println("encrypted ciphertext is" + element);
}
```

**Note:** Consider using [`Character.digit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit(char,%20int)) method instead of subtracting zero:

```
int[] k2Enc = k2CombinedEnc.chars().map(c -> Character.digit(c, 10)).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also deal directly with the encrypted cipher String's bytes.

```
String k2CombinedEnc = in.nextLine();
byte[] encodedBytes = k2CombinedEnc.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)
System.out.println("encrypted ciphertext is: ");
int i = 0;
for(byte element : encodedBytes) {
    System.out.println(" byte " + i++ + ": " + Integer.toHexString(element));
}
```